# how can I DRY this controller code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

These are actions in the same controller:

```
  def world
    @title = 'World'
    @regional = @articles.world.paginate(page: params[:reg_page], per_page: 6) 
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'index_region' }
        format.js { render :file => "articles/latest.js.erb" }
      end  
  end   

  def politics
    @title = 'Politics'
    @regional = @articles.politics.paginate(page: params[:reg_page], per_page: 6)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'index_region' }
        format.js { render :file => "/articles/latest.js.erb" }
      end 
  end

  def sports
    @title = 'Sports'
    @regional = @articles.sports.paginate(page: params[:reg_page], per_page: 6)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'index_region' }
        format.js { render :file => "/articles/latest.js.erb" }
      end 
  end
```

As you can see this code is very repetitive. This goes on for several more entries. Is there a way to DRY this up? Is it possible or advisable to create some kind of block function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to give any wrong ideas here, without digging deeper into your project, but speaking from my experience [(and apparently also in DHHs opinion)](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/) it is always a good idea to stick to RESTfull resources in your controllers.

Basically what your politics/sports/world methods do, is showing more specific instances of articles, right? So what you could do, is (sticking to REST) have an index method like this:

```
def index
  category  = params[:category] || "all"
  @title    = category.humanize
  @regional = @articles.send(category).paginate(page: params[:reg_page], per_page: 6)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'index_region' }
    format.js { render :file => "/articles/latest.js.erb" }
   end 
 end
```

Rendering the same templates in all actions is a very strong hint that you should have them in one method. You will have to rewrite your other code to use the `articles?category=sports` resource, instead of `articles/sports` of course, but imo it is totally worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the controller:-

```
  def custom_method
    @title = params[:title]
    if @title== 'World'
      @regional = @articles.world.paginate(page: params[:reg_page], per_page: 6) 
    elsif @title = 'Politics'
      @regional = @articles.politics.paginate(page: params[:reg_page], per_page: 6) 
    elsif @title = 'Sports'
      @regional = @articles.sports.paginate(page: params[:reg_page], per_page: 6) 
    end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'index_region' }
        format.js { render :file => "articles/latest.js.erb" }
      end  
  end
```

Pass the `title` as parameter in the link.

In `routes.rb`:-

```
get 'news/custom_method' => 'articles#custom_method'
```

This will generate the link as `news_custom_method_path`

Use it in View as:-

```
<%= link_to "World", news_custom_method_path(id: articles.id, title: "World") %>
<%= link_to "Politics", news_custom_method_path(id: articles.id, title: "Politics") %>
<%= link_to "Sports", news_custom_method_path(id: articles.id, title: "Sports") %>
```

You can rename the `custom_method` according to your choice

Comment: how to create routes? `example.com/news/world` `example.com/news/politics` etc

Comment: If someone types `example.com/news/world` into the url, how does the above code generate a route? We never define what the custom_method's are?

Comment: post your `routes.rb`  for this controller and i will update it and also the view code from where you are calling this method.

Comment: right now i was just using `get 'news/world' => 'articles#world'` etc